# Selling your CryptoCoin made with Ethereum

Tags: paypal, bitcoin, ethereum

I have programmed a CryptoCoin in Ethereum with Solidity, a contract based thing and I would like to know how I can make it sellable.

I have this company who wants a crypto currency and they want to be able to buy it with paypal. The problem is, I don't know how I can make my coin available to be bought via Paypal.
I would like to know how I can make this CryptoCoin that I created to go tradable, because they want it that way.

Is there any way of doing this?
Does this have anything to do with the Hash of the Coin or something?

I am using MetaMask as a wallet to control the coin transactions.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah this is doable, well kind of. Here are the potential avenues to look down.

1.) The 'blockchain friendly way' of solving this problem is to use a technology like interledger: https://interledger.org/, essentially their service is providing a decentralized way of performing cross chain transactions. The  idea would be to use interledger to convert paypal payments into ether which can be used to buy your cryptocoin. The drawbacks are: a.) Im not sure if they have developed a paypal plugin (they probably have though and you can check this) and b.) their ethereum plugin is pretty experimental and you would have to have a pretty solid grasp of how ethereum and their tech works.

2.) The 'non blockchain friendly way'. By this I just mean a non decentralized means of doing what you want. create a server that uses the paypal api to listen for when transactions have taken place and then buys eth somehow (no doubt there is an exchange with an api for this purpose) and trades it into your cryptocoin. The drawbacks here are that having such a server that makes payments could be a single point of failure and opens you up to security risks.

Whatever you do, it will be far more complicated than creating the coin itself which is relatively trivial so make sure you have a solid understanding of ethereum and related technologies first if you don't already.